# copy a single file from local Git repository

Tags: git

I need to copy a SINGLE FILE from LOCAL REPOSITORY to my machine, not `git-pull` or `git-fetch`, how can i do it?

Is it possible to get it via hash ? 
such as `a3ea2118bf1c5e2c6aa0974d0b6ff7415bd044ef` ?

Comment: If the repository is local, just `cp` unless it's a bare repo.

Comment: Fetch and clone work just the same locally and over the network, so answers should be the same as for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466735/how-to-checkout-only-one-file-from-git-repository

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`git archive`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html) to obtain a single file from a repository:

```
git archive --remote=file:///path/to/repository.git HEAD:path/to/directory filename | tar -x
```

The repository specified as `--remote` can be local, remote, bare or regular, it works in all of the aforementioned cases.

Note that if you want to obtain a version of `filename` from a specific commit, you can replace `HEAD` in the oneliner above with the hash of the desired commit.